# SQL conditional parameter value

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I need a multiselect parameter to be nullable, so in thinking about workarounds I thought it would be pretty simple if only I could do something like :

```
SELECT STATEMENT{
...
}
IF @Door = null
@Door = '0000'
```

How can you work around null multi-value parameters?

Comment: What's your intention here? If the param is null, then give it a default value? Where and how is the param being used? Is there a door column somewhere? How does SSRS fit into your question?

Comment: I think it must be because of the multi select.  I didn't catch that tag initially.  If it was T-Sql only, he would have had to mention splitted the values for the in statement and usage of the sp_executesql.  Good catch.

Comment: well what I am editing right now is a report file, which is what I assume a .rdl file is, at present it does not matter to me what value goes into it, I just want the report to be able to run when it is null

Answer (score 4):

You can use
where door = coalesce(@door,door)

This will use the @door parameter if it is not null or use the value currently in the door column for that row.

Comment: Is it clear there's a 'door' column? How about the value of `'0000'`?

Comment: Since it wasn't specified, I assumed his convention.   It seems logical that if he is using @door as the parameter that he probably is comparing to a door column.  The name doesn't matter, the pattern still works.

Comment: In the case that there is a default value, he could (assuming 0000 is a default) use coalesce(@door,'0000',door)

Comment: Hey fellas! the data contained within the 'door' column is always a char(4) which contains 4 digits. '0000' in this case is the default value for an item which does not have an associated 'door', so all items that don't have a 'door' should fit this condition.

Thanks for the suggestions hivie! I will give it a go and report back

Comment: Unfortunately, as @Door can potentially be an array I don't see how I can fit this into my sql query :( Or I probably can but don't know how.

Comment: I had mentioned above, that in that case you need to use a split function to join the values in that array, or create a dynamic sql execution using something like sp_executesql.  I would recommend making a stored procedure and have your app/report call it.  It will make the maintenance simpler if you have stored procedures as an option.

Comment: Take a look at this article about using arrays in sql.  This is effectively what you have with multivalue parameters:http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Comment: Thanks for the article hivie, and I do intend to read all of it sometime, but right now I think the workaround I had planned might not even work because the report will not allow me to click the 'view report' button while the Door parameter is empty.

Comment: Thank you good trick. I didn't know this use of coalesce "use the value currently in the door column"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Foo
From Bar
WHERE ((@Door IS NULL AND Door = '0000') 
       OR (Door = @Door))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
SET @Door = COALESCE(@Door, '0000');
SELECT …  /* using @Door */
```

Unless I'm missing something.